# is the package of gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gonna be inUbuntu 20.04

Tags: rhythmbox, webkit

Is gonna be possible to get the package of gir1.2-webkit-3.0 in Ubuntu 20.04 or newer??

I am trying to use the plugin of cover art browser for Rhythmbox, and keeps failing cause is missing the package of gir1.2-webkit-3.0

Answer (score 1):

The package has been deprecated in favor of `gir1.2-webkit2-4.0`. Are you using an old plugin? You can check with its developers if they can update the plugin.

You can try installing the package by downloading it from the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gir1.2-webkit-3.0
(scroll down and download the `amd64` version)

Comment: Thanks . Should I delete the new one then?

Comment: When trying to install it it writes  that The following packages have unmet dependencies

Comment: @yop then you have your answer: "No."

Comment: great! Thanks anywayx